# Determining the domain of $f(t) = 2t + \sqrt{25 - t^2} $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm not sure what to do here. I want to sqrt the $$25-t^2$$  but t is negative. I know I could factor it, but that wouldn't do any good either.

$$f(t) = 2t + \sqrt{25 - t^2} $$

I need to determine why this function is continuous and also state its domain. What should I do? How do I solve this?

Comment: the graph is a tilted semi circle of radius $5$ centered at the origin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\sqrt{g(t)}$ is defined where $g(t)\ge 0.$ In particular, note that $$25-t^2\ge0\\5^2-t^2\ge0\\(5+t)(5-t)\ge0.$$ The product of two real numbers $a$ and $b$ is nonnegative exactly when one of them is zero or they have the same sign--that is, $ab\ge0$ if and only if $a,b\ge0$ or $a,b< 0.$ In order for both $5+t,5-t\ge0,$ we need $-5\le t\le 5;$ we cannot have $5+t,5-t<0.$ (Why?) Hence, the domain of $f$ is $-5\le t\le 5.$

As for continuity, you should be able to show it readily using results about sums and compositions of continuous functions.

Comment: I understand what you mean about the domain, but what do you mean when you say 'using results about sums and compositions of continuous functions.'

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are functions that are continuous at a point $x_0,$ what can you say about the function $f+g$ at $x_0$? If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $g$ is continuous at $f(x_0),$ what can you say about the function $g\circ f$ at $x_0$?

Answer (score 1):

To find the domain ask yourself, where this function is defined. Are you familiar with square roots? For a function $\sqrt{f(x)}$ the domain is $f(x) \geq 0$. Can you handle from here?

Comment: Ah, so t <= 5, otherwise it would be negative under square root and therefore undefined. I see now.

So domain is [-5, 5]